# Replacing logo.png in a subtheme

Tags: 7

So, I created a subtheme, and added a random logo.png (found a random icon online, and renamed it). It worked, of course. Then I got the .png that I actually wanted to use... and the site won't update. I replaced the old logo.png file in the root of the subtheme's folder. The old file doesn't exist anywhere (as far as I know), but it's still showing it over the new logo.png

- I've tried clearing the cache probably 30 or 40 times.
- I've tried clearing my browsers cache, and using different browsers and computers just to make sure it wasn't some local cache
- When I upload a custom logo.png through the theme's administration page, it works, but when I go back to the "default", it goes back to the old one. (I'd like this icon to be the default, not to have to choose a custom one.)

I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

Does your subtheme heritate from another theme? Maybe you can paste your logo in the super theme folder too to erase its default logo as well.

edit: Even if I think that it's not a good thing to change Drupal core or contrib modules/themes directly in the files.

Comment: It does not, but you're line of questioning lead me off to the answer. So +1

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the color module was caching the image. Kind of?

The path to the image that the user was seeing was "site.com/sites/default/color/nameoftheme-randomaplhanums/logo.png." It didn't matter what I replaced the "site.com/sites/all/themes/nameoftheme/logo.png" file with, it was still using the other one. So, I just replaced it.

I'm not sure how to avoid that from happening (maybe uninstalling color? I dunno.) But replacing the image worked. Seeing as how you're not going to constantly changing the default logo that a theme is packaged with that often, I guess it's a viable solution

Comment: I really wish I could accept my own answer sometimes...

Comment: I feel like you still didn't solve it, I think you have some other issues going on here.